# TaskCompletionSource never completes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a websocket connection and I want to make get methods for it. I used this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#tasks-and-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern-eap).

This is a part of the data model:

```
public class Message
{        
    public string MessageType { get; set; }
}

public class SensorData : Message
{
    public float Temperature { get; set; }

    public float Humidity { get; set; }

    public float Pressure { get; set; }
}
```

This is the websocket class:

```
public WebSocketConnection(string url)
{
    socket = new WebSocket(url);
}

private WebSocket socket;

public int Timeout = 10000;

public void Connect()
{
    socket.Connect();
    socket.OnMessage += Socket_OnMessage;

}

public void Disconnect()
{
    socket.Close();
    socket.OnMessage -= Socket_OnMessage;
}        

public event EventHandler<OnSensorDataEventArgs> SensorDataReveived;

private void Socket_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    var msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(e.Data);

    switch (msg.MessageType)
    {
        case "other message types":
            {
                ...                       
            }
        case "SensorData":
            {
                SensorDataReveived?.Invoke(this, new OnSensorDataEventArgs(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SensorData>(e.Data)));
                break;
            }
    }
}

public Task<SensorData> GetSensorData()
{
        var msg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Message() { MessageType = "RequestSensorData" });

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<SensorData>();

    SensorDataReveived += (sender, e) => {
        tcs.SetResult(e.SensorData);
    };

    socket.Send(msg);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

The problem is the GetSensorData method. When socket.Send(msg) is called, the websocket server answers and the event is triggered, but after the SetResult call  there happens nothing. I already tried TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously and wrapping SetResult in a Task.Run but that didn't help.

```
private async void BtnShowSensorData_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sensorData = await connection.GetSensorData(); //Connection is an instance of WebSocketConnection
    labelTemperature.Text = "  Temperature: " + sensorData.Temperature.ToString();
    labelHumidity.Text = "  Humidity: " + sensorData.Humidity.ToString();
    labelPressure.Text = "  Pressure: " + sensorData.Pressure.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Who is calling GetSensorData and how?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto When the User presses a button, the method is called with await and the sensor data should be displayed.

Comment: Well, it *should* happen... please post that code if you expect us to be able to help

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto ok sorry, dind't expect that to be relevant.